# ng-modal not working for form inside modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have a independent modal in a separate file and it's controller in a separate file and the modal is being included in index.html using `data-ng-include`. But the $scope variable inside the modal controller are not getting refreshed with the data provided in the input field present inside the modal.

I have tried to declare the same in main.js but it didn't worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is hard to help with a question about code "didn't worked" when the question does not include any of the buggy code.

Comment: We need more details in order to be able to help

Comment: Share your code and what have you tried so far to help you better.

Comment: New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Issues like this can often be because your scope isn't matching the scope of your modal controller. An example of where this can occur is using `ng-if` around your input as this creates a new child scope.

A quick fix to this may be to add the prefix `$parent.` your input's `ng-model` to instead use the scope's parent scope. However a better more reliable fix would be name the controller's instance variable which you can read more about here: 
https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/ 
and here: 
[AngularJS ng-if and scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787147/angularjs-ng-if-and-scopes)

Comment: The use of `$parent` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. `$parent` is not a robust solution.